# Compiling problems threshold on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

I'm a Ruby programmer and many times I end up on Stack Overflow because of compiling problems on [gems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems), and environment problems like RVM. Other languages also have similar tools, like cabal and pyenv.

While I understand that every programmer uses these tools, and thus it is important to have those questions on Stack Overflow, many times I believe that the question fits better for a system administrator or something, since it is not intrinsically related to the programming language. For example, "Can't compile postgreSQL gem" seems OK, but "can't compile postgreSQL using ulibc" seems less OK, and "Can't apply this patch on postgreSQL gem" seems not related to programming at all.

But the opinions above are mine and mine only, so suddenly appeared: Up to what point are compilation problems and Linux environment issues allowed on Stack Overflow? Is there a golden rule?

Comment: There's definitely a grey area. Many questions are on topic on both sites. If unsure about where to ask something in such a case, pick the site you think most likely to get you a good answer.

Comment: I have searched the unknown word "limiar" and thought it is my lack of English... but actually this is Portuguese word :) And now I see you are Brazil :)

Comment: Oh, I'm terrible sorry. Not sure why, I thought it was valid on English...

Comment: I thought it was a typo for "similar" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I regard compilation problems in general as "too localized," and "can't compile PostGres [anything]" seems pretty far afield.  But I don't necessarily close these questions out of hand if they are well-written, well-researched and answerable.

The tip off is when the question requires you to reproduce their entire environment in order to answer it.

Comment: The intersting thing is that "can't compile PostGres" isn't too localized by the number of upvotes - centainly is not a smart question, so the number of upvoutes should be by the googability of the question.

Comment: That's not what "Too Localized" means.  Too Localized means that the question is unlikely to help anyone else.  Ask yourself this: regardless of the ability to Google the question, what's the likelihood that any of the answers to such a question are ever going to be useful to anyone but the OP?

Comment: Oh, well.. if it is the same compilation error (that is, if you are searching by the line "libxyz...no" instead by "can't compile"), the chances is that the answer will help you. Happened to me many times.